# bigContentView cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-custom-view

I am trying to have a custom bigContentView Ongoing Notification.  The Custom RemoteViews without the bigContenView works just fine.  However, when I tried to add this bigContentView to it, the Eclipse says

"bigContentView cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
    public void PlayTimeOnGoingProgressStatusBar() {        
        NotificationCompat.Builder OnGoingProgress = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        RemoteViews remotetView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        OnGoingProgress.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_name).setContent(remotetView); 
        OnGoingProgress.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        OnGoingProgress.setContent(remotetView);  //Place all custom notifications to here
        OnGoingProgress.setOngoing(true);   //Create OnGoing Status Bar
        OnGoingProgress.setAutoCancel(false);

        OnGoingProgress.bigContentView = remotetView;  //THIS IS THE ONE THAT GIVES ME PROBLEM

        remotetView.setTextViewText(R.id.App_name, “Test”);
        remotetView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, total_time, current_prgoress, false);
        NotificationManager.notify(PROGRESS_STATUS_BAR_ID, OnGoingProgress.build());
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Notification note = OnGoingProgress.build();
note.bigContentView = remoteView;
NotificationManager.notify(... note);
```

Reason: the big content view is a field of the notification class, not the builder class.

Comment: It took me hours and hours, but I never figured it out by myself. I followed your solution and it works!  I am about to cry.  Thank you so much for your kind and help!  Merry Christmas and happy New Year to you